# Which specifications must I do in db2dsdriver.cfg to connect to aDB2 database? I get SQL1532N error

Tags: python, db2, db2-luw

I installed Python 3.4 and ibm_db to connect to a DB2 database; I saw in Python interpreter that ibm_db 2.0.7 is installed, but during connection to a DB2 database, I got the SQL1532N error message, so I think I need to configure `db2dsdriver.cfg` and for that I got the `db2dsdriver.xsd` file, but I don't know what I must change in it. Shall I change all of the "databases" to the actual name of the database in the DB2 instance I try to connect? Or what else must I change?

BTW, there is no `db2dsdriver.cfg` installed in my Windows 10 and regarding some info around I thought it's dynamically created from `db2dsdriver.xsd` which is in `\cfg` subdirectory under Python34.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema id="configuration" xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" >
  <xs:element name="parameter">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string" />
      <xs:attribute name="value" type="xs:string" />
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:simpleType name="whitespacesonly">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:pattern value="\s*" />
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
  <xs:element name="client">
    <xs:complexType>
     <xs:simpleContent>
       <xs:extension base="whitespacesonly">
        <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:attribute name="hostname" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:attribute name="listname" type="xs:string" />
      </xs:extension>
     </xs:simpleContent>  
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="configuration" >
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:all>
        <xs:element name="dsncollection" minOccurs="0">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"> 
              <xs:element name="dsn" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                    <xs:element ref="parameter" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
                    <xs:element name="specialregisters" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
                      <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                          <xs:element ref="parameter" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
                        </xs:sequence>
                      </xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>
                    <xs:element name="sessionglobalvariables" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
                      <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                          <xs:element ref="parameter" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
                        </xs:sequence>
                      </xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>
                  </xs:choice>
                  <xs:attribute name="alias" type="xs:string" />
                  <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string" />
                  <xs:attribute name="host" type="xs:string" />
                  <xs:attribute name="port" type="xs:string" />
                  <xs:attribute name="ldap" type="xs:integer" />
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element> 
              <xs:element name="defaultdsn" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element ref="parameter" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
                  </xs:sequence>
                  <xs:attribute name="alias" type="xs:string" />
                  <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string" />
                  <xs:attribute name="host" type="xs:string" />
                  <xs:attribute name="port" type="xs:string" />
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:choice>
          </xs:complexType>
          <xs:unique name="oneDSNforEachAlias">
            <xs:selector xpath="dsn"/>
            <xs:field xpath="@alias"/>
          </xs:unique>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element name="databases" minOccurs="0">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="database" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                    <xs:element ref="parameter" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
                    <xs:element name="specialregisters" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
                      <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                          <xs:element ref="parameter" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
                        </xs:sequence>
                      </xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>
                    <xs:element name="sessionglobalvariables" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
                      <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                          <xs:element ref="parameter" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
                        </xs:sequence>
                      </xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>
                    <xs:element name="wlb" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
                      <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                          <xs:element ref="parameter" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
                        </xs:sequence>
                      </xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>
                    <xs:element name="acr" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
                      <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                          <xs:element ref="parameter" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
                          <xs:element name="alternateserverlist" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
                            <xs:complexType>
                              <xs:sequence>
                                <xs:element name="server" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                                  <xs:complexType>
                                    <xs:simpleContent>
                                      <xs:extension base="whitespacesonly">
                                        <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string" />
                                        <xs:attribute name="hostname" type="xs:string" />
                                        <xs:attribute name="port" type="xs:string" />
                                      </xs:extension>                                    
                                    </xs:simpleContent>                                    
                                  </xs:complexType>
                                </xs:element>
                              </xs:sequence>
                            </xs:complexType>
                          </xs:element>
                          <xs:element name="alternategroup" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
                            <xs:complexType>
                              <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"> 
                                <xs:element ref="parameter" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
                                <xs:element name="database" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                                  <xs:complexType>
                                    <xs:simpleContent>
                                      <xs:extension base="whitespacesonly">
                                        <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string" />
                                        <xs:attribute name="host" type="xs:string" />
                                        <xs:attribute name="port" type="xs:string" />
                                      </xs:extension>
                                    </xs:simpleContent>
                                  </xs:complexType>
                                </xs:element>
                              </xs:choice>
                            </xs:complexType>
                          </xs:element>
                          <xs:element name="affinitylist" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
                            <xs:complexType>
                              <xs:sequence>
                                <xs:element name="list" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                                  <xs:complexType>
                                    <xs:simpleContent>
                                      <xs:extension base="whitespacesonly">
                                        <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string" />
                                        <xs:attribute name="serverorder" type="xs:string" />
                                      </xs:extension>
                                    </xs:simpleContent>  
                                  </xs:complexType>
                                </xs:element>
                              </xs:sequence>
                            </xs:complexType>
                          </xs:element>
                          <xs:element name="clientaffinitydefined" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
                            <xs:complexType>
                              <xs:sequence>
                                <xs:element ref="client" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
                              </xs:sequence>
                            </xs:complexType>
                          </xs:element>
                          <xs:element name="clientaffinityroundrobin" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
                            <xs:complexType>
                              <xs:sequence>
                                <xs:element ref="client" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
                              </xs:sequence>
                            </xs:complexType>
                          </xs:element>
                        </xs:choice>
                      </xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>
                  </xs:choice>
                  <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string" />
                  <xs:attribute name="host" type="xs:string" />
                  <xs:attribute name="port" type="xs:string" />
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element name="parameters" minOccurs="0">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
              <xs:element ref="parameter" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
              <xs:element name="specialregisters" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element ref="parameter" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
                  </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="sessionglobalvariables" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element ref="parameter" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
                  </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:choice>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element name="ldapserver" minOccurs="0">
         <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element ref="parameter" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:all>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Answer (score 0):

The [error message corresponding to SQL1532N](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.messages.sql.doc/doc/msql01532n.html) reads:

> The db2dsdriver.cfg configuration file contains multiple entries for the database alias "database-alias".

which probably means that you *do* have a copy of `db2dsdriver.cfg` in one of the [standard locations](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.swg.im.dbclient.config.doc/doc/r0061058.html). Depending on which driver package you have installed, it might be under `C:\ProgramData\IBM\DB2\<driver_copy_name or other path>\cfg`.

The `.xsd` file describes the *schema* of the configuration file, there is no point in editing it. You need to locate the actual `.cfg` file and remove duplicate database records from it, leaving only one you need.

Comment: Mustaccio thank you for your reply, but its a weird situation, for there is no db2dsdriver.cfg at all, I thoroughly searched my Win10 and it wasnt exist. Later I copied it from a sample file and made changes, but there happened no difference in the error message..

Comment: I will pass the configuration not as comment but as another answer below..